# JS assertion tests - Ruby specs

Tags: javascript, assertions

I am very new to JS and I am coming from some sort of Ruby bg. In Ruby, I am used to writing Rspecs to test my units and my code in general. I have just started my search for the similar option for JS testing and figured you guys could guide me a bit on the topic. What's the best way to write testing units for specs in JS?  Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

This platform is not meant for opinions, but i can give you a few good hints on where to start:

Enzyme is a test library from airBnB with solid documentation.
However this library does not include assertion.

I found the Chai assertion library pretty easy to use, but that's preference,
so try either of these libraries and see what works best.

Addition:
I recommend to familiarize yourself with the node.js enviroment. This way you have a similar dev enviroment to ruby